# VerticalSrollBar is incrementing value twice in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vertical-scrolling

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim val As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        VScrollBar1.Minimum = 0
        VScrollBar1.Maximum = 100
        VScrollBar1.Value = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub VScrollBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles VScrollBar1.Scroll
        If val < 101 Then
            val = val + 10
            TextBox1.Text = val
            VScrollBar1.Value = val
            TextBox1.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif,", VScrollBar1.Value)
        Else
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This code has one more issue, value is incrementing no matter you are scrolling upward or downward.
I Have tried to debug it by placing Vscroll value in textbox. May you please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is correct, I have achieved what I wanted to achieve. Now, this code is increasing And decreasing TextBox font size, smoothly.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub VS_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles VS.Scroll
        txtbx.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", VS.Value)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        VS.SmallChange = 5
        VS.LargeChange = 20
        VS.Minimum = 10
        VS.Maximum = 100
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only telling it to increment `val` with `val = val + 10`. The `ScrollEventArgs` can be used to determine if the scrollbar is scrolling upwards or downwards.

```
Private Sub VScrollBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles VScrollBar1.Scroll
    If e.Type = ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement OrElse e.Type = ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement Then
        val = val + 10
    Else
        'Decrement val or do nothing here. I've assumed that you are wanting to decrement val

        val = val - 10
    End If

    TextBox1.Text = val
    TextBox1.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif,", VScrollBar1.Value)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're changing the VScroll value in the Scroll event which makes no sense! You're supposed to read the scroll value in this event or to undo the new value. Check the e.OldValue and e.NewValue properties.
2. Make sure that you assign a valid value for the *Minimum* property of the VScroll that respects the minimum size of the font which is not equals 0. At least 1.

Trying to Guess what are you trying to do, I'd suggest the following:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    VScrollBar1.Minimum = 1
    VScrollBar1.Maximum = 109
    VScrollBar1.Value = Font.Size
End Sub
```

Improved version by [jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)

```
Private Sub VScrollBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles VScrollBar1.Scroll
   Dim fs As FontStyle = Font.Style

   TextBox1.Font.Dispose()

   TextBox1.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", e.NewValue, fs, GraphicsUnit.Point)
End Sub
```

Good luck.

Comment: `dim style = TextBox1.Font.Style TextBox1.Font.Dispose() TextBox1.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", e.NewValue, style, GraphicsUnit.Point)`. (I assume `e.NewValue.ToString` is a copy/paste typo).